# Regex to match 1st and 3rd subdirectory for Google Analytics

Tags: regex

This is what I have so far:

```
^/brands/[^/]+$
```

This has enabled me to match the 1st subdirectory (/brands), but stops at the 2nd subdirectory. I would like to match the 3rd subdirectory (/products) as well.

I'm also looking to match the 4th subdirectory as well. I'm pretty new to coding and understand that [^/]+$ basically says the end of the string should match the previous annotation of not-slash, which is why I believe the regex is stopping the matching at the 2nd subdirectory without the slash.

Comment: can you put an example string and split it into parts of what exactly you want regex to spit out?

Comment: Probably you need `^/brands/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)` then access the captures using group placeholders.

Comment: @mehulmpt

Hope this helps:

   `/brands/brand-A/products`
   `/brands/brand-B/products`
   `/brands/brand-C/products`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

Would you be able to explain group placeholders? I don't exactly know where to put the text to match /products

Comment: Where are you using the regex? In GA Filter group accessors? You may use it like that: `$Ax` - with it, you may access group `x` in field `A` (e.g. `$A1` for Group 1, `$A2` for Group 2, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
^/brands/([^/]+)/[^/]+$
```

Comment: But that only matches `brands` and then 2 subparts while only capturing the second one. It is not what you said you needed (*I'm also looking to match the 4th subdirectory as well.*). Also, if my comment helped you, let me post the answer and explain it much better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally match any amount of subdirs, just add it to the end.
This one does 4.

`/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?)?)?`

Readable version

```
 /
 ( [^/]* )                     # (1)
 (?:
      /
      ( [^/]* )                     # (2)
      (?:
           /
           ( [^/]* )                     # (3)
           (?:
                /
                ( [^/]* )                     # (4)
           )?
      )?
 )?
```